# (iphone) showing activity indicator before heavy ui updating

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview, pushviewcontroller

I'm adding activity indicator view before doing some heavy ui updating (pushViewController takes a while to load view).

For some reason, indicator view doesn't appear until the new viewController is pushed.
(indicator view shows up right before the viewController push animation takes place,
although my intention was to show the indicator while a device takes long time before the animation)

Should I do something more than adding the indicator view as a subview?
I already tried [indicatorView'sSuperview setNeedsDisplay]; before the pushViewController call.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the long-running operation is on the UI thread, this will block the entire UI, including the showing/animating of a spinner.  If you can do some of that on a background thread you'll be better off.  If the time is really being taken up by the view layout itself then you have a problem, but my guess is that most of the time is being taken up by non-UI activity. Feel free to post the code that's giving you trouble, as the problem is a little hard to diagnose without the code

Comment: thanks, code is much complicated, spread in multiple classes. (it essentially loads hundreds files from db, and populate uiview, and prepare for animation). i'll have to dig it a bit before I can even layout what i'm doing exactly.

Comment: I definitely understand, but that db access will hang the ui thread.  Your choices are pretty much to have a non-responsive ui thread, or to split it up.  Good luck with whichever direction you go!

Comment: Basically, if you are loading something on the UI thread, no events will be able to get through the view.  This means if the user clicks a button, they get no response, but it also means that things like the spinner will not animate.  By splitting it up, I meant you would need to separate the part that makes the database call, and put that on another thread.  That would then sync back up with the UI thread when it was done, and THEN you could perform your UI actions, like creating and laying out the views.