# (iphone) How do I show activity indicator when there's heavy UI update?

Tags: iphone, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I tried to show activity indicator while heavy UI update.

My initial failed attempt was

> 1. show activity indicator at view1
> 2. pushViewController (creating view of this viewController takes a long time)
> 3. when view1's viewDidDisappear(when pushViewController's push animation
>      occurs), hide activity indicator

Problem was even though I did call "show activity indicator" before pushViewController, activity indicator wasn't showing because of heavy UI which occurred in creating the view of viewController which was being pushed.

I changed strategy as bellow and it works and I don't get why.

> 1. pushViewController
> 2. show activity indicator at viewDidLoad of viewController
> 3. do the heavy UI loading at viewDidAppear and hide indicator

I was under impression the reason that the indicator didn't show up with the first method was due to heavy UI process.
Please refer to the discussion at link.
[(iphone) showing activity indicator before heavy ui updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517160/iphone-showing-activity-indicator-before-heavy-ui-updating)

If too much UI update on queue caused delayed UI update(indicator not showing up), why the 2nd method makes a difference?

I know that viewDidLoad gets called only when view gets created.
And viewDidAppear gets called when view actually shows up on screen.(hence can be called multiple times)

But is there a fundamental difference which would explain why the 2nd approach of using viewDidAppear works in my situation?

And is there a UI update thread apart from the so-called main thread?
Or main thread is the UI update thread?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First I want to make sure that you're updating UIKit UI on the main thread. This is a must, you shouldn't have to specify a thread when working with UIKit, unless you say to use the main thread, but I think that would be redundant.

I would start the activity indicator in viewWillAppear. Then load everything else in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Yes i'm doing UI updating in main thread. I thought viewWillAppear gets called many times for one view appearance. ViewDidAppear gets called once. Why is viewWillAppear better choice? and Should I maintain a bool var not to load multiple indicator view because viewWillAppear gets called multiple times?

Comment: use an if statement to see if the activity indicator is animating. if it is not, then animate. Your activity indicator should already be created, really helpful if it's in the nib. Just set it to visible and animating when you call viewWillAppear (or viewDidAppear if that better suits your app) and when the UI is fully loaded, set the activity indicator to stop animating and non-visible.